# How to map dynamically created properties to the existing bean and generate getters and setters for the corresponding json properties

Tags: dynamic, javabeans

I want to create a dynamic bean in `java` using dynamically generated properties in `json` .

```
{
    "age":"23",
    "name":"some",
    "messages":["msg1","msg2","msg3"],
    "collge":"jyothishmathi",
    "year":2015,
    "name":vrnda    
}
```

Tomorrow some other data will be added dynamically for this `json`.
bean should generate `property` and map `value`.

Comment: i have a requirement to generate json data dynamically based on fields add but at the same time i want to map that values to java bean ( create that property in bean dynamically with the same name  in json object property name
    and generate getters and setters and map the corresponding value to bean).
    
    for example see this http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com//
    i have not found code at here but my requirement is like that.

Comment: are you going to use the beans in your app? or you just want to generate them and save as a file? What is the requirement?

Comment: i ahve to generate bean and i ahve to validate the data and then need to save in database